Restrict top level folder access and allow subfolders only
I am using nginx as a file explorer for my folder called logs. This logs folder has many folders like folder1, folder2, folder3 etc. and these folders have many sub folders. I want to setup a rule in nginx where I want to restrict access to all main folders i.e. folder1, folder2 and  folder3. But at the same time users should be able to access all subfolders under  folder1, folder2 and  folder3.
